# How can I get my JLabel Icon Images to be high resolution?

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I want to make an application with a small jLabel(50x50) in its corner.

The Problem I now have is that the Image the Label displays is looking really bad.

I also added the same Image as an Icon to a shortcut in windows on my desktop just as a comparison.

[image]

Windows on the left side and Java JLabel on the right.

How can I archive a similar scaling result in Jave with no loss in quality?

It does not need to use JLabel.

Code:

```
    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(path);
    Image img = imgIcon.getImage();
    Image imgScaled = img.getScaledInstance((int) (getWidth()), (int) (getHeight()), 
    Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgScaled);
    label.setIcon(image);
```

EDIT:

If you look at these Google Chrome Icons, they are extremely tiny but still sharp and high resolution, how can I archive this in Java?
[image]

Comment: You should add more details, like which layout manager you're using, the size of the JLabel, etc. JLabel automatically scales the image based on the space it's allocated by how you lay out your component. If you're using a 256x256 icon in a tiny JLabel, for example, you're going to get aliasing.

Comment: I get what youre saying, but how can I get the 256x256 icon to stay high resolution in a for example 20x20 shape? It doesnt have to use a JLabel.

Comment: Think about what you're asking. You want an image to retain the same resolution in a space 5% of its native size? I'm afraid things just don't work that way -- this is why Android apps, for example, include different sets of icons for different display sizes. Even EPS will look chunky if you scale it enough.

Comment: This (multiple sizes), or use vector graphics.

Comment: But if you look at the Google Chrome Icons they just optain 25 Pixels but are still sharp, how is that possible? I edited my question with an example

Comment: That sounds lika an Idea pfau! How  can I display a vector graphic in Java?

Comment: I also got the Icons as a SVG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can to use in `BufferedImage`, this is much higher resolution the `JLabel`.
You can to create `BufferedImage` from .png file with `ImageIO` class.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options, or maybe a combination of this:

1. You're using a weird resolution image for your `ImageIcon`
2. Ratio of width to height is not equal, thus skewed scaling

**EDIT** In case 2, make sure the `JComponent` you're using to fetch dimensions from (the one you're calling `getWidth` and `getHeight` on) has equal dimensions for both width and height.

I cut your left image, at 62px width/height. First row shows that image scaled, second row shows what happens when I scale the source image down to 32px in graphics program first:

[image]

Dimensions, as you can see below, go from 62px up by increments of 10px. Code was run on Java 1.8, Windows 10:

```
void addSeries(Image srcImg, JPanel targetPanel) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i += 10) {
        int dimension = 62 + i;
        Image imgScaled = srcImg.getScaledInstance(dimension, dimension, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

        ImageIcon scaledIcon = new ImageIcon(imgScaled);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(scaledIcon);
        targetPanel.add(label);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 


I get what you want to say.

I checked the image size and it is 512x512. With an image of the size 64x64 I get the same result.

I also changed the JLabel Size to 46x46, same result.

I found out that java thinks that my screensize is 1760x960 pixels, but it actually is 2560x1440 big. So java scales the whole application up?
Could this be the error?

Comment: If I scale the image down to the size of 46x46 it looks blurry, but I want it to be sharp and high resolution even if the JLabel is for example just 10x10 big.
Thats why I would need an image of 256x256 minimum that is then "fit" into the 10x10 box whithout losing its high resolution.

Comment: A 10x10 image is only 100 pixels. Don't expect *anything* rendered within 100 pixels to be *"high resolution"*.

Comment: Andrew if you look at the example image I showed in my question the icon displayed by the windows shortcut is relative to the one displayed by Java sharp. But they are both displayed in the same screen size. If you look at other programms with tiny icons, they are still extremely sharp. How can I archive this in Java?